# lm-sensors reports incorrect chassis fan speed on ASUS M5A78L/USB3 in 12.04LTS

Tags: 12.04, asus, fan, sensors

I recently built a machine based on the ASUS M5A78L/USB3 motherboard and installed Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it. Most of the system sensors were automatically detected and work correctly.

However, when I run `sensors`, both the CHASSIS FAN and CPU FAN fields show the actual **CPU fan** speed. This happens regardless of whether a chassis fan is actually installed. BIOS (v1003, latest) shows the correct readings.

My question is, is it possible to get `lm-sensors` to report the chassis fan speed correctly with this motherboard? And if not, is there some testing/data extraction/programming that I could do to help debug this?

I have already tried `sudo sensors-detect`. It reports that all needed modules are already loaded. I have also tried searching Ask Ubuntu and Google, and could not find a solution.

**Details**

Output from `sensors`:

```
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +37.8°C  (high = +70.0°C)
                   (crit = +83.5°C, hyst = +80.5°C)

atk0110-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
Vcore Voltage:      +1.45 V  (min =  +0.85 V, max =  +1.60 V)
 +3.3 Voltage:      +3.28 V  (min =  +2.97 V, max =  +3.63 V)
 +5 Voltage:        +5.07 V  (min =  +4.50 V, max =  +5.50 V)
 +12 Voltage:      +12.03 V  (min = +10.20 V, max = +13.80 V)
CPU FAN Speed:     4655 RPM  (min =  600 RPM)
CHASSIS FAN Speed: 4655 RPM  (min =  600 RPM)
CPU Temperature:    +50.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)
MB Temperature:     +39.0°C  (high = +45.0°C, crit = +75.0°C)

fam15h_power-pci-00c4
Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:      125.26 W  (crit = 124.77 W)
```

Note that both the CPU FAN and CHASSIS FAN fields report the CPU fan speed. This happens regardless of whether a chassis fan is installed.

Summary from `sensors-detect`:

```
Driver `to-be-written':
  * ISA bus, address 0x290
    Chip `ITE IT8728F Super IO Sensors' (confidence: 9)

Driver `fam15h_power' (autoloaded):
  * Chip `AMD Family 15h power sensors' (confidence: 9)

Driver `k10temp' (autoloaded):
  * Chip `AMD Family 15h thermal sensors' (confidence: 9)
```

Note one missing driver. However, since the driver `atk0110-acpi-0` already reports the fan speeds, it would seem the missing driver is not relevant to this.

Answer (score 0):

For me in the begining when i was on ubuntu 10.10 it was working correctly , but now it is displaying this :

```
ucefkh@01Tek:~$ sensors
atk0110-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
Vcore Voltage:      +1.26 V  (min =  +0.85 V, max =  +1.60 V)
 +3.3 Voltage:      +3.23 V  (min =  +2.97 V, max =  +3.63 V)
 +5 Voltage:        +5.02 V  (min =  +4.50 V, max =  +5.50 V)
 +12 Voltage:      +12.14 V  (min = +10.20 V, max = +13.80 V)
CPU FAN Speed:     675000 RPM  (min =  600 RPM)
CHASSIS FAN Speed: 2909 RPM  (min =  800 RPM)
CPU Temperature:    +17.0°C  (high = +60.0°C, crit = +95.0°C)
```

**High Speed** CPU FAN